# Browser won't download file correcty

Tags: php, file, header, download

I've looked through the site and can't find an answer to my question. I'm trying to make a winrar file (which is 1GB) downloadable from my server and whenever I try, it gives me a winrar file with the same name that is only like 9kb. Here's what I have for the headers. I'm really new to downloadable content so, don't make fun of me. :D

```
header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="java.rar" ');
```

I'm assuming that I need more. hahaha!
I keep seeing people use `header('Content-type: application/pdf');` above their disposition. Does this support `rar` format, or do I need to use it as `zip`?

Comment: 9k would indicate that the script's dying before anything 'real' can get out. How are you sending the file's contents? Remember that PHP has a memory limit by default, and if you're loading the entire file into memory you could exceed that quite easily and kill the script.

Comment: Have you looked at the content of the file?  Is it possible you're sending back page content instead of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your script is timing out and only a small part from 1GB file is being sent. You may try increasing [time limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) but IMO for such a big file you'll have to link directly to make it downloadable.

If you want to count file downloads you may link to a php script which will increase the counter and redirect browser directly to the file afterwards.

Comment: How do I do that? Just redirect to the straight path?

Comment: ha! That's exactly what I did. It works great. Thanks! Seems so obvious, now.